# Rhinomocks: I can't use AssertWasCalled properly

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm having some issues trying to use RhinoMocks to figure out if calling a method in my class under test, a certain number of other methods is being called too.
My class to be tested:

```
public class OrderMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<UpdateOrder>
{

    public virtual IRepository Repository { get; set; }

    public void Handle(UpdateOrder message)
    {
        if (!message.Order.Confirmed) return;
        using (var om = new OperationManager())
        {
            try
            {
                om.BeginOperation();
                LVR.Order.Model.OrderHeader order = ConvertToLocalOrderHeader(message.Order);
                Repository.SaveUpdate(order);
                om.CommitOperation();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                om.RollbackOperation();
                // other stuff here
            }
        }
    }

    internal virtual LVR.Order.Model.OrderHeader ConvertToLocalOrderHeader(Protocol.DTO.OrderHeader order)
    {
        // do stuff here, and call Repository.GetAll<Country>()
    }
}
```

Here's my test method

```
[Fact]
public void ConvertToLocalOrderHeader_GivenConfirmedOrderMessage_CallTheConversionMethods()
{
    // create a partial mock 'cause I want some of the implementation to be the true sut class
    var sut = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<OrderMessageHandler>();
    // create a stub for the repository, in order to avoid hitting the db
    sut.Repository = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IRepository>();
    sut.Repository.Stub(r => r.GetAll<Country>())
       .Return(
           new List<Country>
               {
                   new Country {CountryID = "IT", Description = "Italy"},
                   new Country {CountryID = "US", Description = "United States"}
               }.AsQueryable()
    );
    sut.Repository.Stub(r => r.SaveUpdate<OrderHeader>(Arg<OrderHeader>.Is.Anything));

    // call the method I want to test
    sut.Handle(new UpdateOrder
        {
            Order = order,
            EventId = new Guid(),
            EventTime = DateTime.Now
        });

    // verify that the method has been called (this is useless in my real test, I put it here just to understand why it doesn't work)
    sut.AssertWasCalled(s => s.Handle(Arg<UpdateOrder>.Is.Anything));
    // verify that an inner method (virtual) has been called during the execution of sut.handle()
    sut.AssertWasCalled(s => s.ConvertToLocalOrderHeader(order));                    
}
```

In the 2 `sut.AssertWasCalled` calls, I receive an error Object reference not set to an instance of an object. . The reason is that `sut.AssertWasCalled` make a call to the method i'm verifying... thus

```
sut.AssertWasCalled(s => s.Handle(Arg<UpdateOrder>.Is.Anything));
```

calls

```
sut.Handle(null)
```

And being null the parameter the method throws an exception.
Too bad the problem is that it shouldn't re-call the method but just tell me if it has never benn called before in the test method.
What's wrong here?

**Edit:**

as per suggestion received in the comments, I tried a different approach (given that I don't like the expect/verify flavour). Here's the test method:

```
[Fact]
public void ConvertToLocalOrderHeader_GivenConfirmedOrderMessage_CallTheConversionMethods2()
{
    var mocks = new MockRepository();
    var sut = mocks.PartialMock<OrderMessageHandler>();
    sut.Repository = mocks.Stub<IRepository>();
    sut.Repository.Stub(r => r.GetAll<Country>())
           .Return(
               new List<Country>
                   {
                       new Country {CountryID = "IT", Description = "Italy"},
                       new Country {CountryID = "US", Description = "United States"}
                   }.AsQueryable()
        );
    sut.Repository.Stub(r => r.SaveUpdate<OrderHeader>(Arg<OrderHeader>.Is.Anything));
    Expect.Call(() => sut.Handle(Arg<UpdateOrder>.Is.Anything));
    sut.Replay();
    sut.Handle(new UpdateOrder
        {
            Order = order,
            EventId = new Guid(),
            EventTime = DateTime.Now
        });
    mocks.VerifyAll();       
}
```

Adn here's the error I had:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
Previous method 'OrderMessageHandler.get_Repository();' requires a return value or an exception to throw.
```

The error is thrown by the line of code

```
Expect.Call(() => sut.Handle(Arg<UpdateOrder>.Is.Anything));
```

So, no luck even with this approach...

Any other idea?

Comment: Could you try making the Handle method virtual? I think rhino can't override that method in this case unless you do it.

Comment: mh, you are right... too bad nothing changed in the overall behaviour: I still have the same problem

Comment: I think using Excpect in your case, like in this example http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: given that I don't like the expect/verify pattern, I tried implementing the example you pointed out in my context, but still with no luck.. see edited post for details

Comment: I suggest you get the IRepository in a ctor, since you are expecting in to never be null. That is generally how you would usually inject dependencies. I know this maybe out of place, but it is a better design (imo) for this class and it would solve your problem. If you don't wish to do that just say and I'll try to come up with a solution for this design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what the problem was: the method `ConvertToLocalOrderHeader` should be declared at least `protected internal` in order to let Rhinomocks override it. `Virtual` is not enough, being the testing class a differente class.
Very easy solution for a problem that took me hours to be solved :/